# How to derive Ehrenfest's theorem?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, observables

$$\frac{d\langle p\rangle}{dt}=-i\hbar \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{d\psi^*}{dt}  \frac{d\psi}{dx}+\psi^*\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr(\frac{d\psi}{dx}\Bigr)$$
I didn't know the coding of partial derivative which are inside the integral
There is a question about this on site, but I don't have much experience with bra -ket notation.
[Ehrenfest's theorem derivation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/409680/ehrenfests-theorem-derivation). The first integrand makes sense but I'm completely at odds with the second one

Comment: That integral needs parentheses and a differential.

Comment: Are you asking where the second term on the right comes from?

Comment: \partial which goes to $\partial$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\langle p \rangle = -i\hbar\int\psi^*\frac{d \psi}{dx}dx$$
$$\implies\frac{d\langle p \rangle}{dt} = -i\hbar\frac{d}{dt}\int\psi^*\frac{d\psi}{dx}dx$$
$$\implies\frac{d\langle p \rangle}{dt} = -i\hbar\int\frac{d}{dt}\left(\psi^*\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)dx  \ \ \ \ \text{By Leibniz's Rule}$$
$$\implies\frac{d\langle p \rangle}{dt} = -i\hbar\int \left(\frac{d\psi^*}{dt}\frac{d\psi}{dx} + \psi^*\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d\psi}{dx}\right)dx  \ \ \ \ \text{By the Product Rule}$$